# I want to print "2019 to 2020" currently it shows 2019-04-01 to 2020-03-31

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter, date

In my session I have current session date `2019-04-01 to 2020-03-31` and I want to print only `2019 to 2020`

```
  echo $this->session->userdata('start_date');
     echo "\t to";
     echo $this->session->userdata('end_date');
```

Comment: why dont you store both date separate so you can use it easy way.

Comment: this `echo $this->session->userdata('start_date');` contains `2019-04-01 to 2020-03-31`?

Comment: @PathikVejani  `echo $this->session->userdata('start_date');` in this  `2019-04-01`

Comment: so where is `2019-04-01 to 2020-03-31`?

Comment: see you told this: `In my session I have current session date 2019-04-01 to 2020-03-31`

Comment: You want this via jQuery,  if so split is your friend ?

Comment: @Shree—I think the OP is using a scattergun approach, this really has nothing to do with javascript or jQuery.

Comment: Question tag with jQuery, javascript so why I suggest. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use date format

```
date("Y", strtotime($this->session->userdata('start_date')));
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do something like below

```
$dates = '2019-04-01 to 2020-03-31'; // date from session

$startdate = substr($dates, 0, 10);
$enddate = substr($dates, -10);

echo date('Y', strtotime($startdate));
echo ' to ';
echo date('Y', strtotime($enddate));
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `explode`:

```
<?php
$temp = "2019-04-01 to 2020-03-31";
$test = explode(' to ', $temp);
echo date('Y',strtotime($test[0]))." to ".date('Y',strtotime($test[1]));
?>
```

[Explode](https://www.php.net/explode)

Answer (score 1):

`$data = "2019-04-01 to 2020-03-31";` 
 `$temp = explode(' to ', $data);`

`$str1 = explode('-',$temp[0]);` 
 `$str2 = explode('-',$temp[1]);`

`echo str1[0];` 
 `echo "\t to";` 
 `echo $str1[0];`

Answer (score 0):

```
 $start_date = date("Y", strtotime($this->session->userdata('start_date')));
 $end_date= date("Y", strtotime($this->session->userdata('end_date')));

 echo $start_date ;
 echo "\t to";
 echo $end_date;
```